# Memory Leak in C++/CLI method

Tags: .net, c++-cli, com-interop

I've tracked down a memory leak to this call in my code:

```
BitmapSource snapshot = VideoPlayer.GetCurrentImage();
```

VideoPlayer is a C++/CLI library and the code for this method is:

```
WriteableBitmap^ VideoPlayback::GetCurrentImage()
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
    BYTE *pDib = 0;
    DWORD cbDib = 0;
    LONGLONG timeStamp = 0;

    memset(&bih, 0, sizeof(bih));
    bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    HRESULT hr = m_pPlayer->GetCurrentImage(&bih, &pDib, &cbDib, &timeStamp);

    if (FAILED(hr)) throw gcnew MFException(hr);

    WriteableBitmap^ res = ToWritableBitmap(bih, pDib, cbDib, true);

    CoTaskMemFree(pDib);

    return res;
}
```

and ToWriteableBitmap:

```
WriteableBitmap^ VideoPlayback::ToWritableBitmap(const BITMAPINFOHEADER& bih, BYTE* pDib, DWORD cbDib, bool bInvert)
{
    WriteableBitmap^ res;
    AtlTrace(_T("image size: %d x %d, bitCount: %d, bufferSize: %d\n"), bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, bih.biBitCount, cbDib);

    switch (bih.biBitCount)
    {
        //could there be any other format!?
    case 24:
        //AtlTrace(_T("24bit image not supported!"));
        res = gcnew WriteableBitmap(bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, 72.0, 72.0, System::Windows::Media::PixelFormats::Bgr24, nullptr);
        break;
    case 32:
        res = gcnew WriteableBitmap(bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight, 72.0, 72.0, System::Windows::Media::PixelFormats::Bgr32, nullptr);
        break;
    }
    if (res!=nullptr)
    {
        int stride = res->BackBufferStride;
        res->Lock();

        if (bInvert)
        {
            BYTE* pBuf = (BYTE*)res->BackBuffer.ToPointer();

            BYTE* pDest = pBuf + (bih.biHeight - 1) * stride;
            BYTE* pSrc = pDib;
            //the image is inverted
            for (int y = 0; y < bih.biHeight; y++)
            {
                memcpy(pDest, pSrc, stride);
                pSrc+=stride;
                pDest-=stride;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BYTE* pDest = (BYTE*)res->BackBuffer.ToPointer();
            memcpy(pDest, pDib, bih.biSizeImage);
        }

        res->AddDirtyRect(System::Windows::Int32Rect(0, 0, bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight));
        res->Unlock();
    }   
    return res;
}
```

Calling this method multiple times results in some object being "pinned" and a high DeadThread count when I run `!threads` in windbg. Running `!gcroot` on these dead threads I get:

> DOMAIN(00000000036553A0):HANDLE(Pinned):5417c8:Root: 
>   0000000022423378(System.Object[])->
>   00000000125f0c08(System.Collections.ArrayList)->
>   0000000012d96950(System.Object[])->
>   0000000012e44460(System.Windows.Media.MediaContext)->
>   0000000012e43e80(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher)->
>   0000000012e30480(System.Threading.Thread)

Where the address of `System.Object[]` is always the same.

How do I properly clean up after this call so the thread can finish? Or is it a problem with the C++ code?

Comment: The CLR uses a pinned object array to store statics. I would look for a static ArrayList in the source.

Comment: I think you need to attach more code. My guess will be `ToWritableBitmap` function. Does it not copy data?

Comment: You're saying you get lots of threads, but there is threading in the code you posted. Maybe that's something you should look into?

Comment: @svick: I create a new thread each time I call this code

Comment: @Krizz: Added the ToWritableBitmap function. Does that mean the source of the problem would be the C++ code and not in the C# call/cleanup? Am I not required to free memory after C++/CLI calls that return anything other than a pointer (where I'd use FreeCoTaskMem)?

Comment: Use perfmon.exe and check if enough gen#0 garbage collections are being done.  Usually a problem with code like this.  If not then you'll have to help with GC::Collect().

Comment: At the moment I'm already calling GC.Collect() each time this thread (Task) is run (every minute) just to monitor memory usage/threads. My understanding is the call leaves a reference somehow, which pins the object so it can't be collected nor the thread released as it's still rooted

Comment: Please don't delete the code once you answered your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was creating the BitmapSource in a background thread. Once I called this method using Dispatcher.Invoke the thread leak went away.